# How to clear cache in Edge/Chrome (Shaft engine & Selenium 4.0) Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-edgedriver, clear-cache

I was facing a problem that a web page is always cached when am trying to run an automation script on it however manually its working fine so I'm trying to clear http cache I already did it for Firefox but now I'm trying to clear it for Edge and Chrome browser as they are both using same engine and I tried all possible (available) solutions, but I wasn't able to clear the cache. I even tried to run incognito mode and the page was still cached. I don't know how to approach this issue. Can someone give me any idea how to do this? thanks a lot.

**Note: I'm using shaft engine so am not able to use dev tools to clear cache.**

I tried the following: (Java language)

- adding option --disk-cache-dir=NUL
- adding option --disk-cache-size=0
- adding option --media-cache-dir =NUL
- adding option --media-cache-size =0
- adding option --disable-gpu
- Deleting the cache folder and using default profile attached with this cache folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give an update on the mentioned question, I solved it using dev tools api.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).